# projection for nested array in mongo and node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, monodevelop

hi everyone i am trying to project the cities which are belongs to particular state by taking the country_code and state_code

```js
[
  {
    '$match': {
      'iso2': 'IN'
    }
  }, {
    '$project': {
      'states': {
        '$slice': [
          '$states.cities.name', 1, 1
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

when i tried this i am getting the result but is there any better way to do it
tq [image]

Answer (score 0):

I would do it as follow:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
      "$match": {
      "iso2": "IN",
      "states.state_code": "AG"
}
},
{
  $addFields: {
    states: {
     "$filter": {
       "input": "$states",
       "as": "state",
       "cond": {
         "$eq": [
           "$$state.state_code",
           "AG"
        ]
       }
      }
     }
    }
   },
   {
     $project: {
       cities: "$states.cities.name"
   }
   },
  {
    $unwind: "$cities"
  }
])
```

Explained:

1. Match only documents having iso2=IN and states.state_code=AG
   ( For this stage is good if you have index on at least {iso2:1} or compound index on {iso2:1,states.state_code:1} )
2. Filter only the states with state_code=AG
3. $project the names only
4. $unwind to flatten first array.

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uVJCFIuQclZ)

Comment: Please add to the question the expected output , there is more then one name ...